# access a column aliases in the where clause in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I understand that I may need to do grouping to accomplish this, but I can't quite get it.
Postgresql 8.1

I am needing to limit my result set to Origination > 2017-01-01.
Origination is set in line 11.
It is being returned as a column in Excel and is a date.

Currently it returns results with data going back years and we don't need that.

```
select distribution_stop_information.customer_no,
distribution_line_items.item_number,
distribution_line_items.container_id,
distribution_line_items.item_description,
distribution_stop_information.customer_reference,
distribution_stop_information.bol_number, SUBSTRING(distribution_stop_information.bol_number,1,4) as ODDC,
SUBSTRING(distribution_stop_information.bol_number,9,4) as ODRT,
distribution_stop_information.branch_id,
distribution_stop_information.route_date,
(select count(innerDLI.item_number)-1 from distribution_line_items innerDLI where innerDLI.item_number = distribution_line_items.item_number) as RDLcount,
(select innerDLI.datetime_created from distribution_line_items innerDLI where innerDLI.item_number = distribution_line_items.item_number order by innerDLI.datetime_created asc limit 1) as Origination,
distribution_stop_information.route_code,
distribution_stop_information.stop_name,
distribution_stop_information.stop_address,
distribution_stop_information.stop_city,
distribution_stop_information.stop_state,
distribution_stop_information.stop_zip_postal_code,
distribution_stop_information.stop_signature,
CASE WHEN distribution_line_items.exception_code is not null
    THEN distribution_line_items.exception_code
    ELSE distribution_stop_information.stop_exception_code
    END as ExceptionCode,
distribution_stop_information.signature_file_name,
distribution_stop_information.sign_bitmap_file_exists,
ScanR.item_was_scanned as ScanR,
ScanL.item_was_scanned as ScanL,
ScanD.item_was_scanned as ScanD
from distribution_stop_information
inner join distribution_line_items on distribution_line_items.unique_id_no = distribution_stop_information.unique_id_no
left join distribution_item_scans ScanR on 
    ScanR.item_sequence_no = distribution_line_items.item_sequence_no
    and ScanR.stop_unique_id_no = distribution_stop_information.unique_id_no and ScanR.scan_type = 1
   left join distribution_item_scans ScanL on 
    ScanL.item_sequence_no = distribution_line_items.item_sequence_no
    and ScanL.stop_unique_id_no = distribution_stop_information.unique_id_no and ScanL.scan_type = 2
    and ScanL.scan_datetime between to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and ( to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + interval '1 day' )
left join distribution_item_scans ScanD on 
    ScanD.item_sequence_no = distribution_line_items.item_sequence_no
    and ScanD.stop_unique_id_no = distribution_stop_information.unique_id_no and ScanD.scan_type = 9
    and ScanD.scan_datetime between to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and ( to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + interval '1 day' ) 
where
distribution_stop_information.customer_no in ( '90202' )
and distribution_stop_information.route_date between ( to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ) and ( to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ) 
and distribution_line_items.datetime_created between ( to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - interval '288 hours' ) and ( to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + interval '12 hours' )
```

Update:
I have changed the select to read like this, it seems to be working -- any thoughts on if this is the right way to do it?  It is going to always be looking at just the past 180 days.

```
(select innerDLI.datetime_created from distribution_line_items innerDLI where innerDLI.item_number = distribution_line_items.item_number and innerDLI.datetime_created > to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - interval '180 days'   order by innerDLI.datetime_created asc limit 1) as Origination,
```

Comment: this is a sub-query not an alias.  If you change it to a join then you can add it to your where clause.

Comment: " as Origination" is an alias is it not?

Comment: yes `AS Origination` is an alias.  But what did you change to "fix" it?  You changed the sub-query.  That is why I said the issue is *with the sub-query not with the alias*.  Any more questions?

Comment: Only that my question was if I could access a alias in a Where clause.  As in "Where Origination > '1/1/2017'.  What I did to "fix" it is a work around.  If that answer is "no, you cannot - you need to do it 'this' way" - then no, I have no more questions.

Comment: Except the answer is "yes, you can" -- I will show you in a full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you did it - alias in the column name

```
select 
  -- etc etc 
  (select innerDLI.datetime_created from distribution_line_items innerDLI where innerDLI.item_number = distribution_line_items.item_number order by innerDLI.datetime_created asc limit 1) as Origination,
  -- etc etc
from distribution_stop_information
  -- etc etc
```

Here is how you can put it in the where, alias in the join

```
select 
  -- etc etc 
  Origination.datetime_created
  -- etc etc
from distribution_stop_information 
left join distribution_line_items AS Origination ON Origination.item_number = distribution_line_items.item_number
where Origination.datetime_created > to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - interval '180 days'  
-- etc etc
```

> There is nothing about this that is **better** than the solution you posted (the sql optimizer should result in the same plan) but it is "using an alias in the where clause"

Comment: That makes sense Hogan, thanks for taking the extra time with it.

Answer (score 0):

This moves it to the join, which should work for you.

```
select distribution_stop_information.customer_no,
distribution_line_items.item_number,
distribution_line_items.container_id,
distribution_line_items.item_description,
distribution_stop_information.customer_reference,
distribution_stop_information.bol_number, SUBSTRING(distribution_stop_information.bol_number,1,4) as ODDC,
SUBSTRING(distribution_stop_information.bol_number,9,4) as ODRT,
distribution_stop_information.branch_id,
distribution_stop_information.route_date,
(select count(innerDLI.item_number)-1 from distribution_line_items innerDLI where innerDLI.item_number = distribution_line_items.item_number) as RDLcount,
o.Origination,
distribution_stop_information.route_code,
distribution_stop_information.stop_name,
distribution_stop_information.stop_address,
distribution_stop_information.stop_city,
distribution_stop_information.stop_state,
distribution_stop_information.stop_zip_postal_code,
distribution_stop_information.stop_signature,
CASE WHEN distribution_line_items.exception_code is not null
    THEN distribution_line_items.exception_code
    ELSE distribution_stop_information.stop_exception_code
    END as ExceptionCode,
distribution_stop_information.signature_file_name,
distribution_stop_information.sign_bitmap_file_exists,
ScanR.item_was_scanned as ScanR,
ScanL.item_was_scanned as ScanL,
ScanD.item_was_scanned as ScanD
from distribution_stop_information
inner join distribution_line_items on distribution_line_items.unique_id_no = distribution_stop_information.unique_id_no
left join distribution_item_scans ScanR on 
    ScanR.item_sequence_no = distribution_line_items.item_sequence_no
    and ScanR.stop_unique_id_no = distribution_stop_information.unique_id_no and ScanR.scan_type = 1
   left join distribution_item_scans ScanL on 
    ScanL.item_sequence_no = distribution_line_items.item_sequence_no
    and ScanL.stop_unique_id_no = distribution_stop_information.unique_id_no and ScanL.scan_type = 2
    and ScanL.scan_datetime between to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and ( to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + interval '1 day' )
left join distribution_item_scans ScanD on 
    ScanD.item_sequence_no = distribution_line_items.item_sequence_no
    and ScanD.stop_unique_id_no = distribution_stop_information.unique_id_no and ScanD.scan_type = 9
    and ScanD.scan_datetime between to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and ( to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + interval '1 day' ) 
inner join (select innerDLI.datetime_created as Origination, innerDLI.item_number from distribution_line_items innerDLI where innerDLI.item_number = distribution_line_items.item_number order by innerDLI.datetime_created asc limit 1) o
on distribution_line_items.item_number = o.item_number
where
distribution_stop_information.customer_no in ( '90202' )
and distribution_stop_information.route_date between ( to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ) and ( to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') ) 
and distribution_line_items.datetime_created between ( to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - interval '288 hours' ) and ( to_date(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + interval '12 hours' )
and o.Origination > '2017-01-01'
```

Comment: It is saying "Error: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "distribution_line_items";  I changed my select slightly which seems to be working, updating question to reflect.